# sql query or subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have a table called cities with the attribute path (can have duplicate or more equal entries), name and kms, and i need to filter it so that i have entries with only one entry of each for path with the highest kms. what i have now is

```
SELECT cities.* 
FROM cities, categories 
group by cities.path , cities.kms 
ORDER BY cities.kms desc
```

the problem is that it gives me back duplicated entries for path( wich i dont want) and also it doesnt order it by kms like i want. What should i do?

Comment: Can you edit to add your output + your desired output?

Comment: You should show some sampel data from your table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no purpose for the `categories` table in your query, so I have eliminated it in my answer.

```
SELECT c1.path, c1.name, c1.kms
    FROM cities c1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT c2.path, MAX(c2.kms) AS Maxkms
                        FROM cities c2
                        GROUP BY c2.path) q
            ON c1.path = q.path
                AND c1.kms = q.Maxkms
```

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY path` only with `MAX(kms)`:

```
SELECT cities.path, MAX(cities.kms)
FROM cities
GROUP BY cities.path
ORDER BY cities.kms desc
```

`ORDER BY` should order by `kms`, unless it is not of type numeric may be string. Ensure its type.